# Cannot get the Custom UI context menus working in Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written several custom UI Ribbon menus for both Excel and Word. I have working custom context (right click) menus with my Excel apps, but cannot seem to get them to work in Word. I used the same coding as with my working menus in Excel and wrote the XML using the "Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office" so there should be no issue.

I will post my code. The real question is will this type of custom menu work in Word at all?

The XML in the ribbon code is (showing the last lines only):

```
</tabs>
</ribbon>

    <contextMenus>
            <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
                    <dynamicMenu id="mnuMain" label= "BidSmart Contract" imageMso="DocumentTemplate" getContent="GetContent" insertBeforeMso="Cut"/>
            </contextMenu>
        </contextMenus>
```

The getContent sub, "GetContent" looks like this:

```
Sub GetContent(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
```

Dim xml As String

```
xml = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & _
    "<button id=""mnuCtxtEmail"" label=""Send and Email"" imageMso=""TableSharePointListsRefreshList"" screentip=""Send an Email to the Client, Designer or Contractor..."" onAction=""mnuEmail""/>" & _
    "<button id=""mnuCtxtEnvelope"" label=""Print an Envelope"" imageMso=""WhatIfAnalysisMenu"" screentip=""Create an Envelope addressed to the Client, Designer or Contractor..."" onAction=""mnuEnvelope""/>" & _
    "</menu>"

returnedVal = xml
```

End Sub

Comment: If you are using the same ribbon XML you won't get your XL context menu to work in WD. You need to find the correct idMso for the context menu in WD that you want to add your menu to. You can get the control ids here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Comment: Thanks...that did it. Word has a lot of Context menu types....Now how do I flag this as solved???

Comment: Please mark the answer below as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same ribbon XML you won't get your XL context menu to work in WD. You need to find the correct idMso for the context menu in WD that you want to add your menu to. You can get the control ids here: [Office 2016 control ids](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

Comment: Thanks, from my previous reading on the subject I assumed that the "idMso" was a user defined text, like the "dynamicMenu id" or the "button id". It makes sense and now all is working just fine. And, now I am able to control the Row and Column context menus, too.